# Error on jQuery().appendo

Tags: php, jquery, yii

i want to ask about the extensions of jQuery, especially in Yii framework.
i got some stuck on this code :

`jQuery("#repeateEnum").appendo is not a function`

this code is triggered from both of this code :

- `<table class="appendo-gii" id="<?php echo $id ?>">
  <thead>
      <tr>
  </tr>
  </thead>`
- `<?php $this->widget('application.extensions.appendo.JAppendo',array(
          'id' => 'repeateEnum',
          'model' => $model,..
  ?>`

how could i fix it? Thanks for any reply.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the backend code (php) what exactly is going wrong in the frontend code (JavaScript). It looks like your widget code is failing to inject the appendo js file or is injecting it too late or is using the wrong path name in the script. Combing through the output HTML should show which one.

Answer (score 1):

If the library is properly included, check in the JS console for errors when you load the page. Maybe something else is breaking the JS.

Answer (score 0):

have you included following js ?

```
<script src="js/jquery.pack.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.appendo.js"></script>
```

refer live example at http://deepliquid.com/projects/appendo/demos.php

refer another good reference [here](http://sabitlabscode.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/yii-framework-membuat-entry-data-tabel-dinamis-dengan-jappendo/)

Comment: i did. but, nothing's changed. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Yes,, but i think something's going wrong at code : 'id'=>'repeateEnum'. It helps when the Id was auto_increment, but it doesn't work at else

Comment: Thanks for your new references, Hemant. But, that blog was my first tutorial, and i applied jappendo from that. I'm really getting mess because of it.